# Handling this specific Haskell exception

Tags: haskell, exception

I understand that in **Control.Exception**, you need the `evaluate` function to make sure that the expression first evaluates into something and then handle the exception using the `handle` function.

Consider the following code below:

```
import Control.Exception
import System.Locale
import Data.Time

parseDay :: String -> String -> (Integer, Int, Int)
parseDay formatString dateString = toGregorian $ readTime defaultTimeLocale formatString dateString
```

Above is some code to parse dates in strings as its clear from the definition above. This returns type `(Integer, Int, Int)`.

So, I am using the following line of code to see if there was an exception:

```
x = parseDay "%m" "-"
result = try (evaluate $ x) :: IO (Either SomeException (Integer, Int, Int))
```

In this case, the input is bad, so this throws the following exception:

> (*** Exception: readsTime: bad input "-"

But the result is as follows:

> Right (*** Exception: readsTime: bad input "-"

which is something I cannot understand; it should be `Left <error_message>` as shown in all the examples I've seen. I am unsure, what is being lazy evaluated here and why this isn't working as desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `evaluate` is evaluating `x` deeply enough to reach the exception, so `try` is returning a `Right` result and the exception is only really evaluated when `result` is printed.

Try replacing the `$` in `parseDay` with the strict `$!` and see if it works.

Comment: Yep, exactly except that WHNF is not sufficient.  Instead, `import Control.DeepSeq` and replace `$` (or `$!`) with `$!!`.

Comment: I fixed in a different way removing `toGregorian` which is similar to what you stated. So that's cool.